# Openquery insert not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, openquery

I have a linked MySQL -server to MSSQL-server and I am trying to INSERT  data to the table admin_user on the MySQL -server, but end up getting the error:

> Cannot process the object "dbo.admin_user". The OLE DB provider
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYDB" indicates that either the object
>   has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that
>   object.

This works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM openquery([MYDB], 'SELECT * FROM admin_user')
```

This gets the error:

```
INSERT into openquery([MYDB], 'dbo.admin_user') values ('Testi','Testaaja','me@google.com','koe','','','','','','1','N;','','')
```

Here are the rights of the user whom I used for creating the ODBC-connection

> | xx.xxx.xxx.xx | me | *qweqweqwdq2edqdadasd|
>   Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           |
>   Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | N
>   | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y
>   | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y
>   | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y
>   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            |
>   Y                      |          |            |             |
>   |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0
>   |        | NULL                  |
>
> ```
> >     | %             | me | *asdasadasdsadasdasdsad| Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           |
> > Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y
> > | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y        
> > | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y         
> > | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y            
> > | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            |
> > Y                      |          |            |             |        
> > |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0
> > |        | NULL                  |
> ```

My catalog is bitnami_magento, I have the provider string configured with

> DRIVER=(MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver); SERVER=
>   XX.XXX.XXX.XXX;PORT=3306;DATABASE=bitnami_magento;
>   USER=me;PASSWORD=mypass;OPTION=3;

Also I have unchecked the "Level zero only" box from Provider Options (MSDASQL) and made sure that ad_hoc queries are allowed. What I am doing wrong?

There are the instructions that I followed
http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

Comment: I tried inserting as root@localhost from MySQL -server and it worked fine. User me has all the rights so I do not know why it can not insert with openquery

Comment: Have you tried the insert without the 'dbo.'

Comment: Yes. It makes no difference in the error msg.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query:

In the OPENQUERY() you have to use the MySQL table name instead of the MSSQL one (if you want to insert into the MySQL table).

The following syntax should work

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([MYDB], 'SELECT * FROM mysqlDbName.mysqlTableName') VALUES
('Testi','Testaaja','me@google.com','koe','','','','','','1','N;','','')
```

Please change the `mysqlDbName.mysqlTableName` to you MySQL database and table name accordingly.

Comment: Actually you just need the MYDB (with or without brackets), since it is the name of linked database defined in Linked server properties as "Linked server:" the provider string will take care that you will use the "right" database

Comment: Thats true, this is the full syntax. Also please note, that I added the `SELECT * FROM` part to the `OPENQUERY`

Comment: Your query still needs the dummy where clause otherwise it will be slow, since it will get a result set. You should set it so that it will not get any results e.g where 1=0

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I am an idiot. The syntax for Openquery expects a result set to be returned.

So it apparently needs a "dummy query" to be incorporated as a part of the actual query so it will get the result set in response. Writing "where 1=0" makes the query faster as it will not get any actual results in response.

Working example:

```
 insert openquery(MYDB, 'select firstname from admin_user where 1=0') values ('3','Testi','Testaaja','me@google.com','koe12','koe22','','','','0','0','1','','','')
```

> OpenQuery requires a result set to be returned, but UPDATE, DELETE,
>   and INSERT statements that are used with OpenQuery do not return a
>   result set.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270119/fi